# How can I expose the status of an Amazon Lambda function in my web app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm hoping to use Amazon Lambda to run some background tasks for my web app. These particular tasks will only need to run once for the app (not once per user), so I'd like any user to see in the UI if a task is already running, and I'd like to disable the UI that allows them to start that task again.

Does Lambda offer a way to check the status of a function to see if it is running? If not, what is the best way to persist this info to my web app? Am I taking the wrong approach here altogether?

Comment: I'd say this is the wrong approach. If you need to maintain state such as have-never-run/am-running/have-run then persist these to a DynamoDB table or even to S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda functions are supposed to be stateless and keeping functions stateless enables AWS Lambda to rapidly launch as many copies of the function as needed to scale to the rate of incoming events. While AWS Lambda’s programming model is stateless, your code can access stateful data by calling other web services, such as Amazon S3 or Amazon DynamoDB.